# DB Browser for SQlite not responding

Tags: sqlite

When I run the below update query it causes the DB browser to stop responding with no error code is anyone able to help?

```
update Table1
set Column1 = (SELECT Column1 FROM [Table2] WHERE Table1.column2 = [Table2].Column2)
```

Also there is just short of 200k rows on the DB don't know if this will mak much difference.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for this query.

Comment: Sorry but I am very new to SQLite and do not know what that is

Comment: You just stick `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` in front of the statement.

Comment: this is the output that I get                                                                                                               "0" "0" "0" "SCAN TABLE Table1"
"0" "0" "0" "EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 0"
"0" "0" "0" "SCAN TABLE Table2"

Comment: An index on `Table2.Column2` would help.

Comment: Any update on this issue ?